# The URLs mentioned in Google Search Console redirects to another website

Tags: google-search-console, redirects

Google Search Console reported structured data issues on my WordPress blog. When I clicked on those URLs then I am redirected to a Canadian Pharmacy Website (this is a spam site)

However, if I copy paste that URL in browser then I can open that site easily.

I checked WordPress Admin and also did Malware Scanning. It seems site is working fine. I also updated plugins, and change to default theme. But I still get the same results.

What could be wrong? Google is crawling that Canadian Pharmacy Website and not my website.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's explain again:

Your site is hacked.
When you browse the site just by browsing to it, then it works OK.
But when the user comes via Google, then it shows the pharmacy content / redirect
That is called a conditional hack.

So someone hacked your site so it shows different content when you visit the site via Google. The same situation happened to me about my site and was redirected to an adult ads network but after searching a lot i found my site hacked.

To solve it you will need to check into the site and find / remove the hack
see https://aw-snap.info/articles/spam-hacks.php
You might need to ask your developer to check.

Comment: Thanks man; this is really helpful. I will work on this.